# Structure objective-c classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to structure a class that has a to many relationship in it?

I come from a C# background. So let me show you how I would do it in C#.

```
class User {
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Code to access Items:

```
User u = new User();
u.Items = new List<string>();

u.Items.Add( "foo" );
u.Items.Add( "bar" );

foreach( string s in u.Items ) {
    Console.WriteLine( s );
}
```

How do I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: What do you mean by 'best' way? What you've described is very simple to get a rough equivalent in Objective-C, but won't leverage a lot of the more powerful features, so not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: @CarlVeazey By "best" I mean: how would a seasoned obj-c coder implement this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn ObjC in detail:
 Class in ObjC: right click -> create new file and select ObjC class
 Each class have property in .h file for you to access outside. Ex list here is NSMultableArray

```
//USer.h
@interface User: NSObject
{}
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
@end

//User.m
@implementation User
-(id)init{
 if (self = [super init]){
   self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
 }
 return self;
}
@end

//In other class
#import "User.h"

User *u = [[User alloc] init];
[u.items addObject:@"foo"];

[u.items addObject:@"bar"];

for (NSString *aStr in u.items) {

  NSLog (@"%@",aStr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is just a language, it does not contain any framework per se. As C# doesn't have `List` which comes from .NET framework.

First you need to learn the language by reading one of many guides around, from example the official one from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html). Then you can read some reference to Foundation, which is the framework with most basic library support (for lists or other generic elements). You can start from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html). Take a look at `NSString`, `NSMutableArray` and so on.

Comment: It may be technically true that Objective-C is separate from any framework, but in practice the language is nearly inseparable from Foundation. It's rather pointless to learn the language without learning quite a bit about the Foundation framework at the same time.

Comment: @caleb: Here we talk about technical things, and in fact Objective-C does not require Foundation. They are two different things. In any case in my answer I explicitly explained: first learn the language, and then learn the framework so what are you complaining about? It's pointless to know what an `NSMutableArray` is without understanding how a class is declared and used. And specifically, do you think that your point is worth a downvote?

Comment: I'm saying it'd be a better answer if you didn't distinguish between Obj-C and Foundation. Nobody learns the language in a vacuum; one of the first things anyone learns about Obj-C classes is that they're almost always derived from NSObject, and that's where a number of fundamental features (e.g. memory management) come from. So to suggest that the OP *first* learn the language *and then* learn Foundation is somewhat misleading. *I* know what you're saying, but a beginner probably wouldn't. As for downvoting, I only do it with good reason.